# Execute code if a Firebase function times out

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there a built-in method to execute code in a Firebase function if it times out?

I would also like to be able to execute code when the function ends (no matter how it ends). I'm thinking this would behave like `catch` and `finally` in a `try` block.

Is this possible in a Firebase function or must I implement my own timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mechanism provided for this.  Furthermore, implementing your own timer is prone to failure because Cloud Functions will forcibly terminate any code left running after a timeout or crash.  You really have no guarantee that any function code will reliably complete after it has been started.

Your best bet is to understand and [enable retries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries), then write code in your function to determine if your fallback code should run during a retry execution.  Your function should strive to complete without any errors in order to tell Cloud Functions to stop retrying a background event that would trigger the function.